# Does iJson.items() load the entire JSON file into memory before iterating?

Tags: python, json, ijson

I've recently started using iJson to iteratively pass through my JSON data. I will be working with HUGE JSON files (100+ GB).

The docs for iJson are quite limited and did not mention much, so they were of little help in answering my question.

Does iJson.items() load the entire JSON file into memory when called upon?

```py
list = ijson.items(in_file)
# Does this load the entire contents of in_file to memory?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Loading everything immediately would defeat the entire point of `ijson`, which is to not do that. You can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson/tree/master/ijson/backends) for the various backends (the [pure-Python backend](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson/blob/master/ijson/backends/python.py) is the default) if you want to confirm it.

Comment: This helps me a bunch -- Thank you!